# UITableViewCell Pushing to Url

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am making an app where I need to have links to url's inside f my tableview. My question is how can I have one cell leading to one website and another cell leading to another website. If you have any questions for me leave them in the comments below.

Comment: This is a basic question. There are tons on tutorials for this. What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

You have your controller that sets up the table via `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`, right? You can, or maybe already are, implementing `tableView(UITableView, didSelectRowAt: IndexPath)`, which is how to execute some code when the user taps on your cell.

You probably also have a list of url objects (`let myURLs: [URL] = ...`) that you want to push to. You can get the URL you're looking for by the `indexPath` passed in the function (if your whole table view is one section, it'd just be `myURLs[indexPath.row]`; if you have sections, you need to figure out which URL is the right one). Open the url with `UIApplication.shared.open(url)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Tableview Delegate method like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    let url = URL(string: "http://www.google.com")!
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
```

Note: Don't for get Implement **protocol UITableViewDelegate**

[image]

Comment: This is great but I am making an array of table view cells and I need each cell to go to a different url depending on the cell title or name how can I do that with the code you provided. @Sour LeangChhean

Comment: you can use this: 

       let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        guard let address = cell?.textLabel?.text else{ return }
        let url = URL(string: address)!

Comment: You can see in my picture @Luc

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the push segue

```
func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "Push" {
            //This refers to the second view controller
            let vc = segue.destination as! yourSecondViewController

            //selected indexPath
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

            //gets the url from that array indexPath
            let object = urlArray[indexPath!.row]

            //create a variable called url in your second view controller and call it like this
            vc.url = object


        }
    }
```

In your second view controller, use the variable url however you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's work for you

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let urlName = self.arrUrlName[indexPath.row] 
    //self.arrUrlName : whatever your array name, i hope your array contains only url
    let url = URL(string: urlName)

    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```